# How can I perform incremental backup for MongoDB which is not replicaset( StandAlone) on Azure Kubernetes Services(AKS)?

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have setup mongodb on Kubernetes cluster on Azure(AKS), and I am not sure where will be the conf file for changes. I want to setup incremental backup for this deployment on AKS, its showing me `error "2022-03-08T10:21:54.536+0000 namespace with DB local and collection oplog.rs does not exist".`

Please help me with incremental backups on standalone Mongodb Server.
I am using mongodump command as `- mongodump --host=xx.xx.xx.xx --port 27017 -d local -c oplog.rs -u username --authenticationDatabase admin -p password --out="/var/opt/baclup"`

Is there any way without changing to Replicaset?

Also, how do I know where **MongoDB** is installed on the pod?

Answer (score 0):

You can take the backup using different ways Manual, Port-forward, Cronjobs

- Manual using command

Go inside the POD of mongodb and run the command

```
kubectl exec -it <mongodb-pod-name> -- mongodump --out ./mongodb/backup <Update your command as per need >
```

or

```
kubectl exec -it <mongodb-pod-name> -- mongodump --dbpath /data/db --out ./mongodb/backup
```

Or collection backup

```
kubectl exec -it <mongodb-pod-name> -- mongodump --collection MYCOLLECTION --db DB_NAME --out ./mongodb/backup
```

- Port-forwarding

Proxy the port to local machine

```
kubectl port-forward svc/mongodb 27027

mongodump --collection MYCOLLECTION --db DB_NAME --out -u USERNAME -p ./mongodb-backup
```

- Automated using cronjob

Cronjob will hit the MongoDb service save the backup and upload it to GCP bucket or S3 bucket you can configure as per need.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: mongodb-backup
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: mongodb-backup
            image: mongo:4.4.0-bionic
            args:
            - "/bin/sh"
            - "-c"
            - "/usr/bin/mongodump -u $MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME -p $MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD -o /tmp/backup -h mongodb"
            - "tar cvzf mongodb-backup.tar.gz /tmp/backup"
            #- gsutil cp mongodb-backup.tar.gz gs://my-project/backups/mongodb-backup.tar.gz
            envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: mongodb-secret
            volumeMounts:
            - name: mongodb-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /data/db
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          volumes:
          - name: mongodb-persistent-storage
            persistentVolumeClaim:
              claimName: mongodb-pv-claim
```

Ref : https://www.cloudytuts.com/tutorials/kubernetes/how-to-backup-and-restore-mongodb-deployment-on-kubernetes/

> Also, how do i know where MongoDB is installed on the pod ?

Is there any way without changing to Replicaset?

If you know Replica set thn you know the answer of above question.